# In Entity Framework, how to delete record with foreign key constraint?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method to delete a "project" record in the database, and all the "option items" associated with it.

```
public bool DeleteProjectById(int id)
{
    using (DbContext db = new DbContext(ConfigHelper.Instance().ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var entity in db.ProjectOptionItems.Where(o => o.ProjectId == id))
                db.ProjectOptionItems.DeleteObject(entity);

            db.SaveChanges();

            var project = db.Projects.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
            db.Projects.DeleteObject(project);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorLoggingService.Log(this, e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. But if I comment out the first call to **db.SaveChanges**, which is by the way how I was hoping the code will be, this will result to an SQL exception (*The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint*).

Having two calls to SaveChanges() works but surely this is not the way to do it. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: in your db if you set delete cascade, you dont need all foreach loop, this is the one possible solution.

Comment: you need to clear child collection first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like AliRiza said, set it in your SQL server. Additionally use this in your `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOptionItems>().WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

Comment: What is ProjectOptionItems? Asking for a reference but not telling me how to resolve.

Comment: @nzondlo: See the code of the original post. Ronalds object name was `ProjectOptionItem`. Replace it with the object you want to cascade.

Comment: Thanks, but am using Entity 4.x in VS2010, I don't think I have the option to use it. Was also going to use a stored proc now to handle deletes (that's another story)

Comment: @nzondlo: Of course you have the option. But additionally you must set the cascade for the SQL database to get things working. Configuring the model is important if you let Entity Framework create your database.

Comment: I used Code First. Database was already there.